# How to raise an event in a ViewModel from within a subview's ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have an application with a main view that contains several subviews. The views have a corresponding ViewModel that display some data and monitor events contained in models.

Let's say the main view looks like this:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="MyView" Name="myView">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:MySubView Name="mySubView" someProperty="{Binding DataContext.someField, ElementName=myView}"/>
        [...]
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

and the sub view looks like this:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="MySubView"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    [...]
</UserControl>
```

Then in MySubViewModel.cs, some event happens and a function is called with parameter:

```
public Event EventHandler<SomeClass> MySubViewEvent;
[...]
void foo() {
    SomeClass o = new SomeClass(...);
    MySubViewEvent.Invoke(this, o);
}
```

Now, in MyViewModel.cs, I do not have a direct reference to the subview and thus cannot say something like

```
subViewModel.MySubViewEvent += OnSubViewEvent;

void OnSubViewEvent(object sender, SomeClass param) { ... }
```

I can add some property to MySubViewModel and make it dependent on some field in MyViewModel with a dependency property, but 1. how can I do it the other way round such that some callback or event handler will be called in MyViewModel when the event is raised in MySubViewModel, and 2. can I somehow pass event handlers as dependency properties?

Or should I use something else than DependencyProperties for this?

What is the most effective way to achieve this?

Comment: 1) What kind of event is happening in the subview? 2) The subview has a reference to its viewmodel. I would have the view call a method on its own viewmodel. The sub-viewmodel would then raise an event. The sub-viewmodel's parent viewmodel can subscribe to events on its own children as needed.

Comment: @EdPlunkett 1) It receives some data over the network in some model in a collection inside the SubViewModel
2) "The sub-viewmodel's parent viewmodel can subscribe to events on its own children as needed" how to do this is kind of the whole question. The parent does not have a direct reference to its children viewmodels as the sub-viewmodels are auto-wired to the subview

Comment: What receives data, the viewmodel or the view? This whole situation is an illustration of why view-first design is such a bad idea. If you can’t fix the design, I guess you’ll need some kind of Rube Goldberg Locator kludge. You’re paying a very high cost for the dubious benefit of moving some constructor calls from one class to another.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I don't get what you mean? The Model receives data from the network. This is then added to a collection in the Viewmodel, and displayed in the View. In my case I have two sub viewmodels; one that displays data from the network, and another that displays data from a database. I want to keep the network logic and the database logic separate; that's why I've made them into different subviews. However, now I want to update the database view when something happens on the network.
What design would you propose?

Comment: How did it come to pass that the parent viewmodel has no references to its own children? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @EdPlunkett It uses the prism ViewModelLocator to locate the right ViewModel contained in a Unity Container.

Comment: I’d go with Haukinger’s idea. Once you’re committed to one of these frameworks, they’ll have workarounds for the problems they create. The question should have said that you’re using a framework, sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: well, maybe it was kind of unclear from me, I just included the Prism tag but didnt specify it in the question. At least you made me realize this way of doing it is not the default way but a specific way of decoupling code in the Prism library. That didn't really waste my time.

Comment: Glad I added something! I should've noticed the tag though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textbook example for using the `EventAggregator`, though I should add that child view models are also a textbook example for going view model-first. The `ViewModelLocator` is most useful for independent top-level views...

That being said, in sub view model:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<MySubViewEvent>().Publish();
```

Somewhere else:

```
public MainViewModel( IEventAggregator eventAggregator )
{
    eventAggregator.GetEvent<MySubViewEvent>().Subscribe( OnSubViewEvent );
}
```

Comment: I Totally forgot about the EventAggregator!